# Why my monkey is rendered with only a mesh?

Tags: rendering, mesh, shortcut

[image: my monkey is in a problem]
I'm totally noob to the blender world, and I accidentally made my monkey like above.
the monkey was originally a solid not mesh. I managed to find the way for restoring my monkey to solid again in the dropdown list at the Object > Viewport Display > Display As. However, I wonder if there are some shortcuts to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click that dropdown you can assign a shortcut key, but personally I don't use this feature very often, so I've never set one.

The usual way is to use the <kbd>Z</kbd> key to change the viewport rendering mode (note this is for all objects in the viewport).  You can also use the buttons in the top right of the viewport.

Comment: Ooh... then I think my blender is weird, because even if I used the `z` key and set to the rendering or whatever mode, my monkey is still rendered only meshes...

Comment: it was caused by `quick smoke`. `quick smoke` make my monkey be displayed as wire. so the monkey didn't react to change render mode, however, I'm not sure this is intended behavior.

Comment: Viewport Display > Display As forces the viewport to only display your mesh with that setting.  This is independent of viewport setting to allow you to override the viewport.  Yes it is intended because you want to see the volume render, not the surface when using smoke/fire/etc. So this is what I would epect from the quick smoke speed setup.   All important lessons though :)

Comment: Thank you all I really want to vote up yours but I don't have enough reputation ;(. though I really thanks for answers again

Comment: You can accept as answer, then others know that the quesetion is closed.